# React Context and useCallback API refresh in child component best practice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I am using the Context API to load categories from an API. This data is needed in many components, so it's suitable to use context for this task.

The categories can be expanded in one of the child components, by using a form. I would like to be able to tell `useCategoryLoader` to reload once a new category gets submitted by one of the child components. What is the best practice in this scenario? I couldn't really find anything on google with the weird setup that I have.

I tried to use a state in CategoryStore, that holds a boolean refresh State which gets passed as Prop to the callback and can be modified by the child components. But this resulted in a ton of requests.

This is my custom hook `useCategoryLoader.ts` to load the data:

```
import { useCallback } from 'react'
import useAsyncLoader from '../useAsyncLoader'
import { Category } from '../types'

interface Props {
  date: string
}

interface Response {
  error?: Error
  loading?: boolean
  categories?: Array<Category>
}

const useCategoryLoader = (date : Props): Response => {
  const { data: categories, error, loading } = useAsyncLoader(
    // @ts-ignore
    useCallback(() => {
      return *APICALL with modified date*.then(data => data)
    }, [date])
  )

  return {
    error,
    loading,
    categories
  }
}

export default useCategoryLoader
```

As you can see I am using useCallback to modify the API call when input changes. `useAsyncloader`is basically a useEffect API call.

Now this is `categoryContext.tsx`:

```
import React, { createContext, FC } from 'react'
import { useCategoryLoader } from '../api'
import { Category } from '../types'

// ================================================================================================

const defaultCategories: Array<Category> = []

export const CategoryContext = createContext({
  loading: false,
  categories: defaultCategories
})

// ================================================================================================

const CategoryStore: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const { loading, categories } = useCategoryLoader({date})

  return (
    <CategoryContext.Provider
      value={{
        loading,
        topics
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CategoryContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default CategoryStore
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the variable `date` comes from in `CategoryStore`.  I'm assuming that this is an incomplete attempt to force refreshes based on a timestamp?  So let's complete it.

We'll add a `reload` property to the context.

```
export const CategoryContext = createContext({
  loading: false,
  categories: defaultCategories,
  reload: () => {},
})
```

We'll add a state which stores a `date` timestamp to the `CategoryStore` and create a `reload` function which sets the `date` to the current timestamp, which should cause the loader to refresh its data.

```
const CategoryStore: FC = ({ children }) => {

    const [date, setDate] = useState(Date.now().toString());
    const { loading = true, categories = [] } = useCategoryLoader({ date });
    const reload = useCallback(() => setDate(Date.now.toString()), []);

    return (
        <CategoryContext.Provider
            value={{
                loading,
                categories,
                reload
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </CategoryContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I think that should work.  The part that I am most iffy about is how to properly memoize a function that depends on `Date.now()`.